# Appended div not located properly

Tags: javascript, css, dom

My code:

```
<body>                                      
     <div id ="container" style="position:relative;margin-top:50px;width:100px;height:100px;border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;"/>
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Append</button>             

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function myFunction() {
            var tooltipdivRect = $("<div id=" + "ToolTip></div>");
            $(tooltipdivRect).css('top', '20px', 'left', '0px', 'width', '20px', 'height', '20px', "border-color", 'red', 'border', '2px solid #a1a1a1', 'position', 'absolute');
            $(tooltipdivRect).html("check")
            document.getElementById("container").appendChild(tooltipdivRect[0]);
        }
     </script>             
</body>
```

When I append the tooltip `div` it can't append the exact location.. I set the location top as 20 but it was appended at 50... because the parent div position as relative... i need to append the tooltip div exact location what i mentioned

How do I solve this without change the position(both parent and child)?

Comment: If you're using jQuery please tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was the .css() call. The only style was being applied to your element was the top : 20px.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r60c23L5/)

This is your method call:

```
$(tooltipdivRect).css('top', '20px', 'left', '0px', 'width', '20px', 'height', '20px', "border-color", 'red', 'border', '2px solid #a1a1a1', 'position', 'absolute');
```

This is the way it needs to be with your css styles inside of a object.

```
$(tooltipdivRect).css({
    'top': '50px', 
    'left': '0px', 
    'width': '20px', 
    'height': '20px', 
    "border-color": 'red',
    'border': '2px solid #a1a1a1', 
    'position': 'absolute'
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

So, let's say you just want to insert a **tooltip** to your div `#container`

The way you are doing it is trying to insert manually a div that behaves as a tooltip. As you created it: `var tooltipdivRect = $("<div id=" + "ToolTip></div>")`;

My suggestion is either you do something more clean like:

```
function myFunction() {
    var tooltipdivRect = $("<div id='manualTooltip'></div>");
    $(tooltipdivRect).html("check")
    $("#container").append(tooltipdivRect);
}
```

Using a extracted css like this:

```
#manualTooltip {
    top : 20px;
    left : 0px; 
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px; 
    border-color: red;
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**OR** you just set a title for your div container:

```
function appendTitleToDiv(){
    $("#container").attr("title", "check");
}
```

You can see both solutions here in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epbuw2sm/

Comment: i need to show the tooltip out of the div(container)... without changing position.....

Comment: So, when you click on the button, you need to show your tooltip right below (not inside) the div container?